# Maintaining rotation during Quaternion normalization

Tags: quaternions

I've been studying Quaternions for an upcoming project and have come across a conceptual problem that I can't wrap my head around.

The way to normalize a quaternion is as follows:

```
q_mag = sqrt(q0^2+q1^2+q2^2+q3^2)
q0 = q0/q_mag  
q1 = q1/q_mag   
q2 = q2/q_mag  
q3 = q3/q_mag
```

Straight forward and just like normalizing any other vector. But my question is how does this normalization method retain the same rotation information. Using the definition of a quaternion representing an axis-angle representation like below,

```
angle = 2 * acos(q0)
x = qx / sqrt(1-q0*q0)
y = qy / sqrt(1-q0*q0)
z = qz / sqrt(1-q0*q0)
```

Since the normalization operation scales the x,y,z values equally, the axis around which you are rotating never changes. But the value of the angle itself changes drasticly with a normalization operation.

So wouldn't it make more sense to use a method that preserves the value of q0 and only adjusts the other points to reach normalization?

Comment: If the answer was helpful you may want to accept it, otherwise let us know what may still be unclear!

Answer (score 5):

**Math answer:** A unit quaternion represents a rotation in 3D space. Any other (i.e.: non-unit) quaternion does not represent a rotation, so the formula angle = 2 * acos(q0) does not apply to these quaternions. So there is no change of angle when normalising, because the quaternions that you would normalise do not represent rotations in the first place.

**Programming answer:** Floating point operations have accuracy issues. These issues result in small errors, which if accumulated may become large errors. When multiplying two unit quaternions, the mathematical result is another unit quaternion. However the floating point implementation of unit quaternions multiplication may result in a quaternion with a norm close to 1 but not equal 1. In this case we shall normalise the quaternion to correct the error. When we normalise we divide q0 by the norm which is very close to 1, so there is no major change in the value of q0. Because we normalise early the norm is always very close to 1 and we don't need to worry about the precision.

Late answer, but I hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of a necro, sorry, but i think this might be useful for future readers.

Unless I'm thoroughly mistaken, it's actually preferable not to preserve the angle when normalizing to account for rounding errors (in the context of using quaternions to represent rotations, especially in games). Let me explain why:

let's say you have two quaternions (I'll refer to them as `Q1` and `Q2` from here on out) that are supposed to represent rotations, but are not unit due to a rounding error, and you want to multiply them (I'll call the result `Q3`. We also want this to be a unit quaternion). Let's suppose `t1` is a variable, that, when multiplied with every component of `Q1`, `Q1` becomes a unit quaternion (that means `t1` is one divided by the euclidean length of `Q1`, but that really is not relevant here. `t2` does the same thing for `Q2`. If we now multiply the quaternions post-normalizing (ie `Q3 = (t1*Q1)(t2*Q2)`)we get the following:

```
Q3.w = t1*Q1.w*t2*Q2.w - t1*Q1.x*t2*Q2.x - t1*Q1.y*t2*Q2.y - t1*Q1.z*t2*Q2.z
Q3.x = t1*Q1.w*t2*Q2.x + t1*Q1.x*t2*Q2.w + t1*Q1.y*t2*Q2.z - t1*Q1.z*t2*Q2.y
Q3.y = t1*Q1.w*t2*Q2.y - t1*Q1.x*t2*Q2.z + t1*Q1.y*t2*Q2.w + t1*Q1.z*t2*Q2.x
Q3.z = t1*Q1.w*t2*Q2.z + t1*Q1.x*t2*Q2.y - t1*Q1.y*t2*Q2.x + t1*Q1.z*t2*Q2.w
```

which can be rewritten as

```
Q3.w = (t1*t2)*(Q1.w*Q2.w - Q1.x*Q2.x - Q1.y*Q2.y - Q1.z*Q2.z)
Q3.x = (t1*t2)*(Q1.w*Q2.x + Q1.x*Q2.w + Q1.y*Q2.z - Q1.z*Q2.y)
Q3.y = (t1*t2)*(Q1.w*Q2.y - Q1.x*Q2.z + Q1.y*Q2.w + Q1.z*Q2.x)
Q3.z = (t1*t2)*(Q1.w*Q2.z + Q1.x*Q2.y - Q1.y*Q2.x + Q1.z*Q2.w)
```

in other words, `Q3=(t1*Q1)(t2*Q2)=(t1*t2)(Q1*Q2)`. As you can see, normalizing in this way after the multiplication results in the same quaternion as normalizing both inputs pre-multiplication. This means we only have to normalize right before we apply the rotation to a vector/mesh/point, instead of after every calculation, since it produces the same result regardless of how far the quaternion drifts from being unit.

Now let's look at the same calculation, but with an angle-preserving way of making a quaternion unit (the `t` variables now make the quaternion unit when multiplied with only the non-real (aka xyz) parts):

```
Q3.w = Q1.w*Q2.w - t1*Q1.x*t2*Q2.x - t1*Q1.y*t2*Q2.y - t1*Q1.z*t2*Q2.z
Q3.x = Q1.w*Q2.x + t1*Q1.x*Q2.w + t1*Q1.y*t2*Q2.z - t1*Q1.z*t2*Q2.y
Q3.y = Q1.w*Q2.y - t1*Q1.x*t2*Q2.z + t1*Q1.y*Q2.w + t1*Q1.z*t2*Q2.x
Q3.z = Q1.w*Q2.z + t1*Q1.x*t2*Q2.y - t1*Q1.y*t2*Q2.x + t1*Q1.z*Q2.w
```

notice how the non-real components of `Q3` no longer have a common factor This means that normalizing `Q3`post-operation in this way may result in a different quaternion than the one you'd get if you normalized `Q2` and `Q1` in this way pre-operation.

Normalizing a quaternion is not a cheap operation, so it is preferable to use the non-angle-preserving way for stuff like games, since you'd need to use it less often, especially when compositing a large number of rotations. I'm not sure if the same holds up for other quaternion operations, but considering you'll probably be multiplying quaternions alot it is, at least in my opinion, preferable to use the non-angle-preserving way.

Comment: We multiply quaternions to compose rotations. Games is not my domain, but I guess we would multiply quaternions to add more rotation to the current camera rotation, for instance if the player is moving the mouse to look somewhere. This would happen once by timeslice so normalizing there would be cheap. The heavy operation would be applying the rotation to all the objects on the scene (then projecting them to a 2D plane representing the screen). But this is not a quaternion multiplication and does not require normalization. Am I pointing out a flaw in your answer, or do I understand your wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response exactly. The point in my answer is that if you combine alot of rotations you can use the non-angle preserving method after multiplying and get the same result you would've gotten if you normalized at every step. This is not the case with the angle preserving method, which would lead me to believe angle preserving method is likely to actually introduce errors into your angles.

Comment: ie a rounding error would introduce a small error in the angle, and by preserving it you preserve the angular error as well. Considering neither method completely undoes the rounding error I would assume the non angle preserving method is preferable, as it is cheaper to use (only needing to be called once for every object, rather than once for every rotation)

Comment: My point was: I don't think games require a lot of rotations combinations (q q). They sure require a lot of vector rotations (q* v q), but these don't need normalization.

Comment: In addition to the above, I do not believe we have the luxury of choosing when to normalize. We only ever want unit quaternions: whenever we multiply 2 of them we normalize the result to account for rounding errors during the operation. I am also unsure why you believe there are "angle-preserving" and "non-angle-preserving" normalizations: if the quaternion is non-unit, the real component does not represent the angle of a rotation. In practice we just divide each component by the norm.

Comment: "angle-preserving" in this case simply refers to what the asker was questioning. I'm not saying there is an angle to be preserved per sé, but it is easier to refer to what was being asked this way. Also, like I mentioned in my answer, you don't have to normalize at each step, as it gives the same result when you only normalie before applying the combined rotation to a vector. Also, games typically have about 2-4 rotations on each object, depending on the situation, which I would argue is quite a few.

Comment: OK for the term "angle-preserving", at this point I forgot OP's question :) You are right that we don't need to normalize often. I was under the impression games did not combine rotations that much. Scene objects should have no rotation, but now that I think of it objects such as other players might have quite a few! Thanks for the constructive replies.